# Django Filter query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've a column in my model where I store a list of barcodes. Now I've a barcode, 123456. I want to filter that row with the barcode 123456

```
class A(models.Model):
    barcode = models.Charfield(max_length = 255)
```

I store barcode as `[u'123456', u'457798799']`, ie each barcode row contains a list of barcodes in Char format.

Now I want to filter that row which has barcode `123456` in its list. How can I do that?

Comment: So you store '[u"123456", u"234234"]', as a string?

Comment: Yes. That string can be converted back to list.

Comment: I just dont want to check every row one-by-one

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be:

```
A.objects.filter(barcode__contains='123456')
```

With that you would get a list of all objects which barcode contains the desired string.

Anyway, I would recommend to use a `ForeignKey` relation, as it is a proper semantic solution:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=50)

class Bcode(models.Model):
    barcode = models.IntegerField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

Then you can get all the Barcodes from an `A`-instance:

```
a_instance.bcode_set.all()
```

and you can get the according `A`-instance for a barcode for example:

```
b = Bcode.objects.get(123456)
b.a.name
```

Comment: Foreign Key? How? Can you please specify a dummy architecture for using it?